# Can Anyone reuse my .apk file

Tags: android

I had a concern about the security of my android app.
I developed an app uploaded it on market and got more than 1 lac downloads. I also uploaded my app on Mobango(android store). On monago a persom can download my app's .apk file.

So if any person acn download .apk file of my app, he can upload it on other android store.

I have tried this I downloaded my app's apk  from mobango and successfully uploaded on other android store.

My concern was anyone can steal my app and reupload with his name.

thanks

Comment: can they steal your code?  Yes.  There is nothing you can really do to absolutely stop that.  But can they impersonate you?  No, because the app is signed with your key, back that thing up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can reuse the .apk file and extract the source from it .......

Answer (score 0):

This is a worry for all app developers on Google Play store. I've seen Google Chrome plugins which allows to download any apk from the store if you're brave enough to put your google login details and the device ID of your phone.

What you can do is obfuscate the content of the APK using something like ProGuard, which makes it hard to decompile.

Comment: Also, potentially, a rooted custom ROM can allow access to downloaded APKs.

Answer (score 0):

[Documents](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) say:

> The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and **obfuscates** your code by
>   removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with
>   semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file
>   **that is more difficult to reverse engineer**.

But you can see that it says `that is more difficult to reverse engineer` and so in **theory** it is **not impossible**.

Note that when you use `ProGuard` tool,you have to  create a `key`.So if any body change your code and recreate another .apk from it this .apk can not publish as update or another version of your origin .apk .